# How to parse HTML in Yaml files with Silex/Symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony, yaml, silex

I use yml text files for storing small paragraph of texts for my Silex/Twig website:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$loader = Yaml::parse('/path/to/file.yml');
```

My files look like:

```
block_2:
    id: 2
    title: "Title"
    body: |
       Lore ipsum <strong>legend</strong>
       Lore ipsum dolorem etc.
```

In my Twig file I display variable

```
<p>{{ block.body }}</p>
```

Now the output is not as expected as carriage returns and html entities are not properly parsed. Instead the text is rendered in browser

```
Lore ipsum <strong>legend</strong> Lore ipsum dolorem etc.
```

How do I properly parse html and line breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, twig escapes all input of the templates. This makes your templates very safe.

In some cases however, it is save to output the raw input. This can be done in 4 ways:

1. Using the [`escape` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html), marking it as safe HTML: `<p>{{ block.body|escape('html') }}</p>` (*best solution*)
2. Using the [`raw` filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html): `<p>{{ block.body|raw }}</p>` (*usefull if you are 200% sure it'll be safe*)
3. Using the [`autoescape` tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html), marking it as safe HTML (this prevents faulty JavaScript from comming in your code): `{% autoescape 'html' %}<p>{{ block.body }}</p>{% endautoescape %}` (*usefull when doing it for multiple inputs in the same section*)
4. By [disabling auto escaping all together](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options) for all templates (*not recommended*)

See also [HTML Escaping](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#html-escaping) in the documentation

Comment: Thank you! Indeed it works. There is a type on 3. use {% %} instead {{ and }}